# ZFS Mounting local filesystem ; eval : zfs not found - eval: touch not found - /etc/rc : date not found

Tags: boot, freebsd, hard-disk, zfs

My main FreeBSD 13.1 installation freezes at some point of the booting process showing these messages :

```
Mounting local filesystem
eval : zfs not found 
eval: touch not found 
/etc/rc : date not found
```

I know that the problem is caused by the incorrect dataset that was mounted by me as a mistake and for this reason now /bin and stuff are missing. I'm not able to figure out how to fix it.

This is the disk "broken" :

```
NAME                                           USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT

zroot                                          412G  33.9G       96K  /mnt/zroot/zroot

zroot/ROOT                                     399G  33.9G       96K  none
zroot/ROOT/13.1-RELEASE-p2_2022-11-11_174736     8K  33.9G      321G  /mnt/zroot
zroot/ROOT/13.1-RELEASE-p3_2022-11-17_193042     8K  33.9G      343G  /mnt/zroot
zroot/ROOT/13.1-RELEASE_2022-09-01_041825        8K  33.9G      308G  /mnt/zroot
zroot/ROOT/31-03-2022-a                        512K  33.9G     43.4G  /mnt/zroot
zroot/ROOT/31-03-2022-b                        399G  33.9G      318G  /mnt/zroot

zroot/tmp                                     15.0M  33.9G     15.0M  /mnt/zroot/tmp

zroot/usr                                     11.2G  33.9G       96K  /mnt/zroot/usr

zroot/usr/home                                 192K  33.9G      192K  /mnt/zroot/usr/home

zroot/usr/ports                               11.2G  33.9G     11.2G  /mnt/zroot/usr/ports

zroot/usr/src-                                  96K  33.9G       96K  /mnt/zroot/usr/src-

zroot/var                                     1.26G  33.9G       96K  /mnt/zroot/var

zroot/var/audit                                 96K  33.9G       96K  /mnt/zroot/var/audit

zroot/var/crash                               1.11G  33.9G     1.11G  /mnt/zroot/var/crash

zroot/var/log                                 3.91M  33.9G     3.91M  /mnt/zroot/var/log

zroot/var/mail                                 130M  33.9G      130M  /mnt/zroot/var/mail

zroot/var/tmp                                 18.1M  33.9G     18.1M  /mnt/zroot/var/tmp
```

I've found 50% of the solution. I've detached every external disks and I've found that this disk :

```
=>        40  1953525095  da4  GPT  (932G)
          40      532480    1  efi  (260M)
532520        1024    2  freebsd-boot  (512K)
533544         984       - free -  (492K)
534528     4194304    3  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
4728832  1948794880    4  freebsd-zfs  (929G)
1953523712        1423       - free -  (712K)
```

interferes with the booting of the disk which contains the zroot pool :

```
=>       40  976773095  ada0  GPT  (466G)
         40     532480     1  efi  (260M)
532520       1024     2  freebsd-boot  (512K)
533544        984        - free -  (492K)
534528    4194304     3  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
4728832  972044288     4  freebsd-zfs  (464G)
976773120         15        - free -  (7.5K)
```

It means that if I boot FreeBSD installed on the disk ada0 and the USB disk da4 is attached to the PC,I get those errors. It looks the installation files of a previous FreeBSD installation that I made on that disk OR I have connected the zroot pool to that disk. The two disks are connected in some way,but I don't know how. So,I want to break that connection. I've checked if there is some errors inside the fstab file,but it does not seem :

```
# Device                Mountpoint              FStype          Options         Dump    Pass#
/dev/ada0p1             /boot/efi               msdosfs         rw              2       2
/dev/ada0p3             none                    swap            sw              0       0
linprocfs               /compat/linux/proc      linprocfs       rw              0       0
linsysfs                /compat/linux/sys       linsysfs        rw              0       0
tmpfs                   /compat/linux/dev/shm   tmpfs           rw,mode=1777    0       0
fdesc                   /dev/fd                 fdescfs         rw              0       0
proc                    /proc                   procfs          rw              0       0
```

maybe the connection is inside the /boot folder of the disk ada0,but I'm not able to understand where it could be. If I boot FreeBSD without attaching the usb disk da4,I don't get those errors and FreeBSD installed on ada0 boot totally and correctly.

This is the content of the disk da4 :

```
# zpool import -f -R /mnt/zroot2 zroot2 
ok

mario@marietto:/mnt/zroot2 # ls 
boot  dev  tmp  usr  var  zroot  zroot2

mario@marietto:/mnt/zroot2 # cd zroot2  

mario@marietto:/mnt/zroot2/zroot2 # ls
Data  Informations      backup
```

As you can see there have been placed the typical files of a zfs pool. Now should be easy for someone of you understanding what to do. Please help me I don't want to detach the disk da4 every time I want to use FreeBSD.

Comment: Check the `mountpoint` and `canmount` properties of datasets in zroot2 - e.g. with `zfs get mountpoint,canmount -r -t filesystem zroot2`.  Does one or more of the datasets have a mountpoint  of `/` or `/bin` (or `/usr` or `/usr/bin` or something else that would mount that pool's datasets in place of the root pool's)?  If so, change it/them. Or just change the top-level `zroot2`'s properties and the children will inherit.  Read up on `mountpoint` and `canmount` ("no" or "noauto" are probably what you need) in `man zfsprops`, and the "Mount Points" section in `man zfsconcepts`.